# How to pass the credential info in a API call with browser?

Tags: api

In a command line mode, the API call would be something like this:

```
curl \
    --request GET \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer dea464c07bd07300095caa8" \
    https://demo.immuta.com/dataSource?size=100&sortField=subscribers
```

Is there a generic way to convert it into one line URL so I can do this from a browser? or this is up to the site's design? or this must be done through curl or python call?

Thank you very much for your enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at an API development tool like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). It will significantly ease development for you.

Comment: Thanks, I am not looking for developing an API solution for my user, in this case I am the user. :)